# How to display the correct tooltip message based on series data in ApexCharts?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I'm working with ApexCharts through the Angular wrapper ng-apexcharts. I have a chart that displays two series of data, and I'm trying to set a custom tooltip that shows a different message depending on which series the data point belongs to. However, I'm having trouble accessing the series data in the tooltip callback.

The data i use is formatted like this :

```
const bad = this.patient.measures.feeling
  .filter(({ value }) => value === 'bad')
  .map(({ date }) => ({ x: date, y: 0 }));

const good = this.patient.measures.feeling
  .filter(({ value }) => value === 'good')
  .map(({ date }) => ({ x: date, y: 0 }));
```

Here's the code:

```
config.graphs.feeling.series = [
  {
    name: this.translate.instant('patient.graph.feeling.good'),
    data: this.filterData(config.seriesData.feeling.good, seeAllData),
  },
  {
    name: this.translate.instant('patient.graph.feeling.bad'),
    data: this.filterData(config.seriesData.feeling.bad, seeAllData),
  },
];

config.tooltip.feeling.custom = [
  ({ seriesIndex, w }) => {
    return `<div class="apexcharts-tooltip-candlestick p-2">${w.globals.seriesNames[seriesIndex]}</div>`;
  },
];
```

My problem is that when i try to use seriesIndex it's always equal to 0, i'm unable to find a way to know if i'm in the 'Good' series or in 'Bad' series.

No mater the data that i hover on, the tooltip callback always logs the seriesIndex to 0

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.